# A convergence criteria

Tags: fourier-series

Question: For $f \in C^{1},$ show that the Fourier coefficients, $c_n(f),~n \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot c_n(f)=0.$$

My approach: 
WLOG assume that the period of $f$ to be $1.$ The Fourier series of is 
$$f(x)=\sum_{ n \in \mathbb{Z}}~c_n \cdot e^{2 \pi i n t}~dt$$ 
and the corresponding Fourier coefficients are given by
$$c_n(f)=\int_{0}^{1}~e^{-2 \pi i n t} \cdot f(t)~dt.$$
Using integrating by parts with $u=f(t)$ and $dv=e^{-2 \pi i n t}~dt.$ Then $du=f'(t)~dt$ and $v=e^{-2 \pi i n t}/{-2 \pi i n}.$ Thus we have
$$c_n(f)=\frac{1}{-2 \pi i n} \cdot \big\{ f(1) - f(0)  \big\}+\frac{1}{2 \pi i n}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-2 \pi i n t} \cdot f'(t)~dt.$$

Now when I multiplied by the $n$ I don't get the desired result. Any help in proving this is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should look at a proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, it is very interesting.

Comment: I fail to see how this is true if $f$ if $f(0)\neq f(1)$. Take $f(x)=x$, so that its fourier coefficients are something like $1/n$, which doesn't satisfy the required limit.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, you are right there is an ambiguity. It is true only if $f$ is $C^1$ AND $1$-periodic, i.e. $f(0) = f(1)$. Otherwise, in the context of Fourier series, if $f(0) \ne f(1)$ then it is not considered continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is periodic $f(1)=f(0)$. Then use Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma to show your second term vanishes as well since $f'\in L^1$.

If $f$ is not periodic. The conclusion does not stand. For example, $c_n[x]\sim \frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}$.

Comment: Periodicity was not mentioned in the problem. May be it is an inherent being  the Fourier series. I'll check that out. Thank you.

Comment: @ManMath: Did you not say "WLOG assume that the period of $f$ to be $1$" in your question?

Comment: Yeah, I made that assumption.

Comment: How is $c_n(f)$ even defined if $f$ isn't periodic?

Comment: @ManMath the problem mentions the Fourier coefficients of $f$, so implicitly $f$ is $T$-periodic and we are given its values on one period. Of course WLOG we can assume $T=1$.

Comment: I fail to see how this is true if $f$ is not periodic, specifically if $f(-1)\neq f(1)$. Take $f(x)=x$, so that its fourier coefficients are something like $1/n$, which doesn't satisfy the required limit.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the helpful suggestions. I didn't use my own assumption and ignorance of Riemann Lebesgue lemma was why I couldn't get the answer. So periodicity is the key part here.

Comment: I did accept the answer @Hans. This didn't allow me to post the comment then.